# Move through long line with up and down keys in vim

Tags: vim, navigation

Given I have a long phrase, say, in line `:12`, as this "example":

```
11 foo bar
12 aasdf aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaazzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
13 another line
14 and another line
```

In vim, the `:12` line would be "splitted", but, given my cursor is located as pointed in this "situation":

```
12 aasdf <MY CURSOR IS HERE>
   aaaaaa.......
   aaaaa...zzzzzz..
   zzzzz....
13 another line
```

When I press `<down> key` my cursor would go to `:13` line.

I'd like to walk through the long line using `up` and `down` keys, as other text editors, and not just jump to next line.

Could anyone help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the commands `gj` and `gk`.

Also, pressing `g<down arrow>` or `g<up arrow>` will do the same.